# How can I diagnose why `npm publish` quietly does... nothing?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've created a npm package following several different sets of instructions online.  Here is what I have: https://github.com/joelarson4/CharFunk/blob/master/package.json

When I do an `npm publish`, I get a single newline of output (no errors, no anything).  But from what I can tell, my package is not on npmjs.org.  https://www.npmjs.org/package/CharFunk is an error page.

How can I figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Nothing looks immediately wrong to me... some (possibly obvious) things to check: Have you done an `npm login`?  Is there an `_auth` in your `.npmrc` file in your home directory?  (Don't paste that here, that's your credentials to npm.)  Have you ever published something before?  You also might try going over the steps they have here (including doing a local install of your package): https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html

Comment: I have done an npm login, which seems to succeed (at least I get no error).  There is no `_auth` entry in `.npmrc`.  I have never published to npm before.  I have followed through https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html precisely, and no errors are logged in any step.  I've set `npm config set loglevel verbose --global` but yet none of the npm commands are reporting more than a single newline.  Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. the fact that there's no `_auth` is interesting... Is there an npm-debug.log file created in the directory after you publish?  Are you able to run `npm install`?  (If so, you're able to at least connect with https://registry.npmjs.org/)  Is there anything (aside from the `_auth`) in the `.npmrc` file?

Comment: I had to rerun `npm adduser` for some reason, and I also needed to change to an all lowercase package name.  Additionally, my loglevel was stuck at silent, which I fixed by manually editing `./nmprc`

Comment: yay! congrats on the first package published :)

Comment: It is all lowercase, as you've written in the package.json's `name` field. https://www.npmjs.org/package/charfunk

Answer (score 19):

You solved your problem, but for others; You might see more information with:

```
npm publish --verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have loglevel set to silent.  Try doing

```
npm config set loglevel verbose --global
```

and then rerunning your npm commands to see if that gives more useful detail.

If not, try editing `~/.npmrc` and setting

```
loglevel verbose
```

The extra information provided should help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did have similar problem working with our local Nexus server.

NPM v6 is not able to handle the HTTP Status 302. It understands this code as success printing `npm http fetch PUT 302` into verbose output. It happened in my case, as the Nexus server expected the connection over https and the firewall redirected all the requests from port 80 to 443.

To fix it, I changed the `publishConfig` in the `package.json` referencing the Nexus server over `https`.

```
"publishConfig": {
  "registry": "https://nexus.example.com/repository/npm-private/"
},
```

NPM v8 handles redirects correctly and doesn't need this fix.